# Turnstile package

Tags: symbols, fontsize, logic, turnstile

I am fairly new to TeX, so I may be missing something simple, but I can't seem to adjust the height of the turnstile objects produced by the `turnstile` package. In particular, if the symbol appears as a subscript it does *not* adjust to match the surrounding text. Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Please add to your question a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with the vertical scaling is documented in the *Conclusions* section of the file [turnstile_article.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/turnstile/turnstile-en/turnstile_article.pdf):

> For a future version of this package,
>   we want to look at changing the height
>   of the turnstile sign. This will take
>   into account the heights of the
>   expressions above and below, similar
>   to the way we currently allow for the
>   widths of the expressions.

In particular, since no provision is made for vertical scaling, the symbol will not scale appropriately when used in a subscripted expression (See first part of the example below).

The first idea that comes to my mind is to use `\scalebox` (from the `graphicx`) package to scale the turnstile symbol. The following example shows both the actual behaviour with no vertical scaling, and the definition and use of a new command attempting to alleviate this problem; of course, feel free to make the modifications that best suit your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{turnstile}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\Subsststile[2]{%
  \,\scalebox{0.8}[0.5]{$\sststile[ss]{\textstyle#1}{\textstyle#2}$}\,
}

\begin{document}

The standard command with no vertical scaling:
\[
  A_{\Gamma\sststile[ss]{}{}P} \qquad A_{\Gamma\sststile[ss]{aaaa}{b}P} 
\]

The newly defined command, with vertical scaling:
\[
  A_{\Gamma\Subsststile{}{}P} \qquad A_{\Gamma\Subsststile{aaaa}{b}P} 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: turnstile example]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different version that scales (but via an optional argument):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\turnstile[3][2]{%
  \mathrel{\calcturnstile{#1}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\tsvstyle\vdash$}%
  \setbox2=\hbox{$\vcenter{\copy0}$}%
  \hbox{\vrule\vphantom{$\tsvstyle\vdash$}}%
  \raise\dimexpr\ht0-\ht2\relax\hbox{$\vcenter{\offinterlineskip
   \ialign{\hfil\kern1pt$\tsstyle##\vphantom{by}$\kern1pt\hfil\cr
           \relax\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\hphantom{\vdash}\kern-2pt\else#2\fi\cr
           \noalign{\kern1pt\hrule\kern1pt}%
           \relax\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\hphantom{\vdash}\kern-2pt\else#3\fi\cr}}$}%
}}
\newcommand\Turnstile[3][2]{%
  \mathrel{\calcturnstile{#1}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\vrule\vphantom{$\tsvstyle\models$}}}%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip
   \ialign{\hfil\kern1pt$\tsstyle##\vphantom{by}$\hfil\cr
           \relax\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\hphantom{=}\kern-2pt\else#2\fi\cr
           \noalign{\kern1pt\hrule\kern\fontdimen22\tsfont2\hrule\kern1pt}%
           \relax\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\hphantom{-}\kern-2pt\else#3\fi\cr}}
}}
\newcommand\calcturnstile[1]{%
  \ifcase#1\let\tsstyle\textstyle\let\tsvstyle\textstyle\let\tsfont\textfont\or
    \let\tsstyle\textstyle\let\tsvstyle\textstyle\let\tsfont\textfont\or
    \let\tsstyle\scriptstyle\let\tsvstyle\textstyle\let\tsfont\scriptfont\or
    \let\tsstyle\scriptscriptstyle\let\tsvstyle\scriptstyle\let\tsfont\scriptscriptfont\fi}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\textstyle \vdash \qquad \turnstile{}{}
\\
X\turnstile{}{}\Gamma\turnstile{a}{bbbb}P\Turnstile{a}{bbbb}Y\models Q
\\
A_{\Gamma\turnstile[3]{x,y}{L}P}
\\
A\turnstile[0]{x,y}{L}B
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The optional argument chooses the style for the objects: 0 is for display, 1 for text, 2 for script and 3 for scriptscript. The default is 2. An empty pair of arguments builds symbols very akin to `\vdash` and `\models` respectively.

[image]

Comment: For me `A \turnstile{}{L} B` looks the same as `A \vdash B`. In other words, when the superscript argument is empty, the subscript doesn't get generated. You can fix it with `A \turnstile{\quad}{L} B` but that doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Comment: @RandyRanderson The minimum width is set using `\hphantom`, you can modify that to suit your needs.