# How can I typeset a long vdash with symbols on top and bottom?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Essentially, I am trying to typeset a symbol in math mode that looks like this: [image: Long vdash with symbols on top and bottom]. Is there any way I can do this easily with a package or do I have to fiddle around with my own commands?

I tried `vdash^*_M`, but this leads to a vdash that is too short and with the * and M misplaced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `turnstile` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

$x\sststile{M}{*}y$ $x\sdtstile{M}{*}y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29091/4427 for a slightly different realization.

Answer (score 2):

There were many stylistic choices (size, placement, etc.) that were left unspecified, so I took a guess.  They of course can be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\ruleoffset{1pt}
\newcommand\specialvdash[2]{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{
  \mkern2mu\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.4pt}{\baselineskip}\stackon[\ruleoffset]{
    \stackunder[\dimexpr\ruleoffset-.5\ht\strutbox+.5\dp\strutbox]{
      \rule[\dimexpr.5\ht\strutbox-.5\dp\strutbox]{2.5ex}{.4pt}}{
        \scriptstyle #1}}{\scriptstyle#2}\mkern2mu}}
}
\begin{document}
$(x+y) \specialvdash{M}{*} y \specialvdash{Q}{+} z \specialvdash{y}{*} p \vdash q$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that solution, it was helpful and I upvoted it. But given that I have to use a package in your solution as well as in the one with the turnstile package, I accepted the other one since it does not involve a complicated \newcommand.