# How can I type these symbols in LaTeX on Hinman's mathematical logic?

Tags: math-mode, logic

On my textbook *The Fundamentals of Mathematical Logic*, I can't produce the symbols below.

[image]

I tried Detexify and the best formula that I can type is: `\vDash_{\!\!\!_\mathfrak{A}}` . How can I type this symbol more elegantly? Furthermore, any solution to produce it in KaTeX is appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/401602/82917

Comment: Right, package turnstile is the way to go. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/turnstile

Comment: It is a bit longer than `\vDash` and `\models` . Though the position of \mathfrak{A} is proper.

Comment: The `turnstile` package is made for this, as @MS-SPO says. It doesn't cohere with other fonts, which is unfortunate, but there's just no support for proper entailment symbols in fonts I'm aware of. The standard symbols are limited and non-extensible. `turnstile` provides a broader range and extensibility.