# Turnstile operator

Tags: logic

How can I make a turnstile operator which can lengthen when it has a subscript?  The `turnstile` package doesn't work with my LaTeX editor. Besides, I don't want to lengthen the vertical bar, only the horizontal bar.

**Example :**

`\vdash` :

```
|-
```

What I'm looking for :

```
|----
  K
```

Comment: There's the package `turnstile`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18917/turnstile-package

Comment: what does "does not work with my latex editor" mean? packages do not depend on which editor you use to write the file.

Comment: when i try to load it i get an error

Comment: Which error? Just a general gripe about the weather or something specific about your use of `turnstile`?

Comment: it says command `\second` already defined. the error appears in the line `\let\oldnorm\norm`