# How to get \vdash with number in Latex

Tags: symbols

i need to get this in Latex, I saw only the \vdash command but I can´t put a number o variable on top :

[image: Latex symbol]

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Can you provide some larger context? What does this symbol/construction mean? Where is it used (in-line, for example)?

Comment: Sure, it's used inline. That means a computational step for a pushdown automaton, see more at : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're lucky! There's the `turnstile` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{turnstile}

\begin{document}

$\Gamma\sststile{}{k}P$

\end{document}
```

You find the documentation with `texdoc turnstile_article` or, online,

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/turnstile/turnstile_article.pdf

Or you can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29091/4427